# Laravel DOMPDF package doesn't work for UTF-8 Characters

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, utf-8, dompdf

I'm trying to use laravel DOMPDF package. I read in documentation that it has UTF-8 support. Everything works fine with Latin symbols but when i try to use UTF-8 characters, question marks appear in PDF. I know there is TCPPDF package for it but before trying this package want to definitely know, if DOMPDF has UTF-8 support.

> $pdf = PDF::loadHTML('აააა');
>
> return $pdf->stream();

Comment: You should probably read the [Unicode How To](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) of the library.

Comment: Also, the laravel project [recommends adding a meta tag](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#tip-utf-8-support) to your document.